# 32 bit process memory leak on x64 processor

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, 32bit-64bit

I made a 32 bit c++ program which is always run on x64 machines. A client is saying that running 5 instances of this process is using causing all of their 24 GB RAM to be used.

Immediately I would think there was a memory leak but I am unable to reproduce this memory issue.

Doing a bit more research into memory allocations I found [Memory Limits for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx). This tells me that a 32 bit process will not be allowed more than 2 GB of memory by the OS.

Is it at all possible that a 32 bit application on a 64 bit windows will be able to have a memory leak use more than 2 GB?

P.S. Killing the process results in the memory being restored to normal operating levels (about 2 GB).

[EDIT] I have now seen that most of the memory being used is Kernel Memory: Nonpaged. Does this mean that it is some system resource which is being used and not a memory leak?

[UPDATE] The problem is not a driver or memory leak. It seems to be a process handle leak. There is something which is continuously starting new handles to a file. This was found using perfmon to monitor the process. As a rule of thumb if a process has more than 2000 to 3000 handles you should investigate. Especially if that number is increasing every few seconds.

Comment: Can't you install windows 64 bit and retest with their data set or retrieve a dump and analyse? This will save you a lot of hassle...

Comment: I am using windows 64 as well. I looked at the process dump on the crash. It told me that it tried to access a memory location and it couldn't. I suspect that it just ran out of memory and when I tried to allocate some memory then it crashed.

Comment: yes, pool memory = driver. analyze the pool memory usage with poolmon/xperf/WPA: http://superuser.com/a/674725 to see which driver caused it

Comment: Consuming 24GB of non-paged pool is not possible by a very long shot.  You are not gathering the right statistics.  Getting a 32-bit process to occupy many gigabytes of RAM is otherwise not very difficult, just write to a file at a very high rate.  Determining how much RAM to dedicate to processes and how much to the file system cache is an OS duty.  It never intentionally avoids using RAM.

Comment: So I found the problem. The one process was binding to a fixed port. When the next process opened then it kept trying to bind to that same port every 500 ms. This thread created a new handle every attempt. The thread handle leak was being stored in nonpaged pool memory. On a 16 GB ram pc this filled up all the memory and there was nothing left for my process to use which caused it to crash. Added a bind attempt limit to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Memory Limits for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx), limit for 32-bit process on 64-bit system is 4 GB with IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE set, thus your 5 processes could consume 20 GB of memory total. This can be set through [LARGEADDRESSAWARE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx) option, which expands virtual address space.

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously possible, as the client is experiencing it.

(maybe you did expect like some ideas how? You don't provide much info or code, so in a very general way I would suggest the memory allocation may be not in the app itself directly. Maybe the app itself will take only ~1-2GiB, but will also stir the OS to do something stupid, like virtual memory map of file of size of 4+GiB, or other devices lock, where the device driver does something stupid, etc...)

You should profile the memory usage on the target system to have idea how much *your* code does use. Then you can try to search for the rest of it.

Comment: We have looked at the task manager commit and working set size and it never exceeds 550 MB. I am not sure if that is what you mean by profiling the memory but I would appreciate if you could elaborate more on this.

Answer (score 0):

In general, using the [/LARGEADDRESSAWARE:ON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx) linker switch can allow a 32bit application use more than 2GB. Also using the [Address Windowing Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366527(v=vs.85).aspx) can allow using more memory. But if you aren't using any of these techniques in your application then it should have the 2GB range. However since the upper 2GB range is used for system resources maybe you are leaking system resources?

Comment: I do not have  /LARGEADDRESSAWARE enabled. Could you please elaborate on how I could be leaking system resources?